# How can I solve the import axios error in chrome-dev-tools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to React programming.I can not look my webpage at local(localhost:3000). When I called `npm start` command I get "compiled successfully !" but at page I see this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5uvz.png).Can you help me ?

I was try making weather-app with axios from site's APİ. I couldn't unfortunately.

Comment: Please include errors as formatted text rather than links to images.